# How to push an object coming from postman to nested object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, nested-object

I'm having a problem in pushing these data to an nested object.

Here is what I put on postman as JSON format:

```
    "productId":"621256596fc0c0ef66bc99ca",
    "quantity":"10"
```

here is my code on my controller

```
module.exports.createOrder =  async (data) => {


    let product = data.productId;
    let oQuantity = data.quantity
    let totAmount = data.totalAmount


    return  User.findById(product).then(user =>{
    
        user.userOrders.products.push({productId:product})
        user.userOrders.products.push({quantity:oQuantity})

        if (user) {

         return user.save().then((savedOrder,err)=>{
        if (savedOrder) {
            return user
        } else {
            return 'Failed to create order. Please try again'
        }

    })
            
        } else {

            return "try again"
        }
    })
}
```

my schema is:

```
userOrders:[
            {
            products:[
                {

                    productName:{
                        type: String,
                        required: [true, "UserId is required"]
                    },

                    quantity:{
                        type: Number,
                        required: [true, "Quantity is required"]
                    }


                }
            ],
    
            totalAmount:{
                type: Number,
                required: [true, "Quantity is required"]
            },

            PurchasedOn:{
                type: Number,
                default:  new Date()
            }
            
        }
    ]
})
```

i got these error on my CLI

```
user.userOrders.products.push({productId:product})
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'userOrders')
```

Currently i wish to just put these data from postman to the nested object but i think im not using the push use-case well. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

`user` is not found and contains `null`. `User.findById(product)` returns an empty result. The ID `product` can't be found in `User`. First, check if the user was found, then, push the products:

```
module.exports.createOrder = async (data) => {
  let product = data.productId;
  let oQuantity = data.quantity
  let totAmount = data.totalAmount

  return User.findById(product).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      return "try again";
    }
    user.userOrders.products.push({productId:product})
    user.userOrders.products.push({quantity:oQuantity})

    return user.save().then((savedOrder, err) => {
      if (savedOrder) {
        return user;
      } else {
        return 'Failed to create order. Please try again';
      }
    });   
  });
};
```

Comment: ok the postman says try again.

here is my routes 

`code`
route.post('/create-order', auth.verify , (req,res)=>{

 let isAdmin = auth.decode(req.headers.authorization).isAdmin;
 let productsOrderId = req.body.productId
 let quantityOrder = req.body.quantity
  let data = {
   productId : productsOrderId,
   quantity : quantityOrder
 }
  if(!isAdmin) {
  controller.createOrder(data).then(outcome => {
   res.send(outcome)
  })
 } else {
  res.send('User is Admin')
 }
 
})
`code`
thank you for helping me. anytips on how users can have its productID value instead of null?

Comment: @exekielvergara If you have a follow-up question, please ask a new question. Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific questions. You asked a question and I answered it. Don't modify your question or ask follow-up questions in the comments.

Comment: Thank you! for the heads up. Pardon me.